# distributing form elements among different webpages,looks simple but not able to fix

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

This question is similar to my previous question but not the same ... please check out....I am using totaly 3 webpages; form elements are distributed among two pages, "eg1.html" and "eg2.html", but all the form elements should be submitted to "eg.php".

```
 Here is the code for eg.php which accepts the form elements from both eg1.html and eg2.html:

 $size=$_POST["fontsize"]; 
 $label=$_POST["label"]; 
 $age=$_POST["age"]; 
 $sex =$_POST["sex"]; 

 code for eg1.html
 <html>   
 <body>   
 <form action="eg.php" method="post">   
 <input type="radio" name="fontsize" value="3"/>   
 <a href="eg2.html">click here to select other options which includes age and sex</a> 
 <input type="radio" name="label" value="stacks"/>   
 <input type="submit" name = "down" value = "down">   
 </form>   
 </body>

 Now What would be the code for eg2.html? just check out sample partial html code :but needs to be compleated....

<input type="radio" name="age" value="3"/>   
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"/>
```

The code should work exactly like this:
First user will open eg1.php he selects only one option that is "fontsize" .. next he clicks on the "link to eg2.html"  to select two more options "age" and "sex" after selecting... he will be redirected back to eg1.php where he has to  select one more option that is "label"  ... then he will submit the form to eg.php. Which will hold all form elements those are 'fontsize' 'age' 'sex' and 'label' .....
I have seen many website using this technique please check out cooltext.com where  user will get an option to click on the font image which will redirect him to fonts page after selecting one of the fonts images he will be redirected back to homepage,where he can select some other form elements or form elements and finally submits the form .... i have also seen many websites using this technique , i think this can be done using JQUERY/JavaScript but not sure ...please help me to fix this problem guyz,.,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using js you can have the entire form on one page and divide it in steps like this

```
<form action="eg.php" method="post">
<div class="step1">
  <input type="radio" name="fontsize" value="3"/>   
 <a href="#" id="step1_submit">click here to select other options which includes age and sex</a> 
 <input type="radio" name="label" value="stacks"/>   
 <input type="submit" name = "down" value = "down"> 
</div>
<div class="step2">
<a href="#" id="step2_back">click here to go back to step1</a> 
<input type="radio" name="age" value="3"/>   
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"/>   
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>   
</div>
</form>
```

js:

```
$('#step1_submit').click(function(){
  $('#step1').hide();
  $('#step2').show();
});
$('#step2_back').click(function(){
  $('#step1').show();
  $('#step2').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply abhidev , but i actually dont want to put in one page  thats my main intension ... thats the reason i have told about cooltext.com where they have implemented the same tecnique and they have used two pages ,,,, but the form will be submitted to only one page

Comment: Hi Abhidev
 i found multi step form submitting check out http://webexpedition18.com/articles/how-to-create-a-multi-step-signup-form-with-css3-and-jquery/ .... i need to distributed form elements in different pages..... just like cool text fonts page ...

Comment: In the article itself all the fields are in just one page. Another reason to keep all the steps of the form is that its easy to implement, validate and is snappy and ajaxy rather than having the page reloads for each step.